# python- reading JSON in ascending order

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse a json file which looks something like this:

```
{ "my_test":[
    { "group_name":"group-A", "results": [
        { "test_name": "test1", "time": "8.556", "status": "pass" },
        { "test_name": "test2", "time": "45.909", "status": "pass" },
        { "test_name": "test3", "time": "9.383", "status": "fail" },
        ...
    }
}
```

how can I print out the test results in ascending order? (by the name or by time)

EDIT:
The output could be in ascending order of time:

```
test1 8.556
test3 9.383
test2 45.909
```

Comment: Other than sorting first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this, using the builtin `sorted` function.

```
from json import loads

json_data = """{
    "my_test": [{
        "group_name": "group-A",
        "results": [{
            "test_name": "test1",
            "time": "8.556",
            "status": "pass"
        }, {
            "test_name": "test2",
            "time": "45.909",
            "status": "pass"
        }, {
            "test_name": "test3",
            "time": "9.383",
            "status": "fail"
        }]
    }]
}"""

data = loads(json_data)

for group in data["my_test"]:
    print group["group_name"]
    sorted_results = sorted(group["results"], key=lambda a: float(a["time"]))
    for result in sorted_results:
        print(result["test_name"] + ": " + result["time"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked here:
[How do I sort a list of dictionaries by values of the dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-values-of-the-dictionary-in-python)

Just extract your list of dictionaries with 
    list_of_dicts = your_dict_name['results']

then

```
import operator
```

and follow the instructions by vemury for example.
"
To sort the list of dictionaries by key='name':

list_of_dicts.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('name'))

To sort the list of dictionaries by key='age':

list_of_dicts.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('age'))
" 
by vemury

Comment: You can flag this question as a duplicate rather than copy from someone else's answer

Comment: The question is not asking about a dictionary. It is asking about an array, which by definition is ordered as specified in the JSON.

Comment: @DavidHammen: You have misread the answer.